# Proving a property of $3 \times 3$ determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

In Basic Mathematics, Serge Lang proves property **D1**.

[image]

I think the subscripts for the determinant I highlighted in the picture must be:

$a_{12}\begin{vmatrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix}$

Is that right? If not, then I’m not understanding the concept.

Comment: You are correct, it should be $a_{32}$.